# Vertical Align Bootstrap panel with CSS

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have had a look at a number of the articles on here which seem to provide a fix for most people, apparently except for me.

I am using the following CSS on my [website](http://www.sheqcomply.com/portal):

```
/* login page background */

body.function-login {
display:inline-block;
float:none;
vertical-align:middle;
height:100%;
background:transparent url("http://sheqcomply.com/loginbackground.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:contain;
}
```

No matter what I try I just cannot get the login box to vertically align within the page.  I can provide the layout css and page html if needed but havent included it within this post as they are large.

The current code results in this
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use often when I have to align things vertically, I position the element at 50% from top and then translate it with -50%. It should work for you too, but it also depends on the other css instructions you have there.

```
.function-login {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both, this has done something in my website preview, but unfortunately on the live website it remains unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Vertical alignment, a perenial favourite.

One way to achieve this is to have another div around the component. In your example this would be the child of `container` with class `col-md-6 col-md-offset-3`. For this you need to add the `height: 100vh` style. For your actual component div you then add the following style

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

There's probably little tweaks you need to do in order to get the "right" alignment for your context, but this should do it.